# In need of guides to maintain the bike that I'm about to get

Tags: hybrid-bike

I'm about to get myself a cheap hybrid (costing ~200 USD) and I'd like to be able to learn how to maintain it on my own without having to go to a bike shop every now and then (and also because I'm a student who can't really afford to do that). If there are any books that could be suggested, that'd be really helpful!

It'd have alloy (6061) frame and rims (double walled). Shimano tourney groupset (3×7), adjustable handlebar stem, quick release seat post as well as both wheels.

Comment: Hi Jerry - take a moment to browse the [tour] to learn what's on and off topic.  "requests for learning material" is off topic, but asking your actual questions is fine.

Comment: When getting an air pump, get one with a built in pressure gauge. @Jerry

Comment: https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help

Answer (score 9):

Link-only answers are frowned upon here but I'm going to provide one anyway

https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help

Park Tool Company's Repair Help web site is the most comprehensive, professional and understandable set of articles and videos on bike repair and maintenance that is out there.

If you run into specific problems, Bicycles Stack Exchange is of course a great resource.

Comment: Agreed, I'd like to add to this answer RJ the bike guy's youtube channel (https://www.youtube.com/c/RJTheBikeGuy/videos) it's very watchable and covers lots of maintenance topics.

Comment: Park Tool also has a general bike repair manual that I would highly recommend

Comment: I second maybe adding more links. There are many YouTube videos for different levels of bicycle maintenance

Comment: @Colin Feel free to add your own answer with that YouTube channel

Comment: @abdnChap Feel free to add you own answer with as many links as you like

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I don't have time right now. Was just agreeing that link-only answer makes sense in this case, but if you know more links, should include.

Answer (score 7):

In short, ride your bike.

- Do a basic M check for safety, monthly.
- Wash your bike when its dirty.
- Lube the chain periodically (depends on your riding conditions)
- And ride safely.

As components and consumables wear, ask specific questions (if we don't already have that covered in a previous Q&A.)

Enjoy riding !

Comment: learning to change punctures is useful too if you want to avoid bike shops. In addition if you cycle in wet weather then you'll want to check your tyres for flints after you ride to avoid them getting embedded.

Comment: The problem is that such cheap bikes often come in need of maintenance or adjustment right from the shop or factory. Badly adjusted brake pads, badly installed cables, badly adjust shifters, handlebars out of alignment, etc. are all too common but can be hard for a beginner to spot if they don’t know what to look or listen for.
You forgot to mention a pump and learning how to change tubes.

Comment: @Michael I left a lot of things out - they are either answered already on the site, and/or could make the answer overly long.

Answer (score 7):

Your area may have some kind of "bicycle collective" with tools, education, and parts (typically used but with some life left), e.g., [1]. Universities may have one.

[1] https://corvallisbikes.org/

Comment: Best idea. Better than books. Meet outside while it's still summer though ...

Answer (score 6):

I've been in the same position before, and I'd highly recommend reading through some of the articles on https://www.sheldonbrown.com/ as you come across problems you need to fix. Sorry for providing just a link but it is very much like a guide book.

I'll often refer to the website when checking for compatible replacement parts, for example!

Answer (score 5):

I can certainly recommend books by Lennard Zinn, namely

[Zinn & the Art of Road Bike Maintenance](https://road.cc/content/review/192116-zinn-art-road-bike-maintenance-lennard-zinn)

and

[Zinn & the Art of Mountain Bike Maintenance](https://www.bikemag.com/gear/accessories/tools/review-zinn-art-mountain-bike-maintenance-6th-edition/)

I think that the mountain bike version would probably be more  suitable for your hybrid bike and it is the version I own. Many of the topics are universal.

The author also often answers questions at his https://zinncycles.com/tag/ask-lennard-zinn/ or other websites.

---

On a different note, there are many highly instructive videos on the web, like on the [GCN Tech](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC710HJmp-YgNbE5BnFBRoeg) channel, [GMBN Tech](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6juisijUAHcJLt23nk-qOQ), the [Park Tool](https://www.youtube.com/c/parktool/videos) channel and many more. Usually it is best to just search for the particular problem you have and try several different videos.

Answer (score 4):

You must definitely buy an air pump and some instruments which help you to tight or loose your brakes,adjust you seat etc.(They come most of the time free with the bicycle).
Air pump is important in my opinion Because tires keep on loosing air due to temperature changes because tires contract and expand and also due weight of the rider.
Maintain your cycle.
Have a quick check of your bicycle before every ride,maybe once in a week.
Keep your bicycle clean this help you to see whether there are not any hidden defectes which might be left unnoticed because of dirt on your bicycle. check your brakes whether they need some lubrication in cable,whether chain needs some lubrication.
Again most important for long time cycling is to have your own air pump.
That is not so costly and is easy to carry.
Take every body's advice on maintaining your bicycle because I know very little about it .

Thanks you.

" ENJOY CYCLING
STAY HEALTHY"